# Placing an image

Tags: css

So I'm new to this whole html css programming. I'm developing a simple site to display my resume. I want to place an image on the right side of my main content. I want to place it there so that I will eventually be able to click on my name and it will slide out using Jquery, but I can't seem to be able to place it about 10px to the right of my main content. Here's my site.

http://students.cs.byu.edu/~drbones/sean_resume/resume.html

And here's the CSS for the main content and image

```
body
    {
        background-image:url('images/darkgreen.png');
        font-family: verdana;
    }
h1
    {
        text-align:center;
    }
.main
    {
        padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    }
.page
    {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        width:800px;
        border: solid black;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        background-color:#E8E8E8;
        border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
.profile_image
    {
        float:right;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
```

PS - Any helpful hints on the resume content would be helpful too for all you CS employers out there ;)

Comment: So your resume says you know HTML and CSS, mhhh? :P

Comment: As someone who has sifted through resumes,

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you want the end result to be. But `float:right` will be relative to the `body` of the document. You may want to put in page instead.

Comment: Hey thanks guys. Just to clarify, I'd like the image to be in the dark green area, on the right of the grey body content, hugging the right border of the div about 15px or so, even when you resize the window horizontally. With the code I have if I resize the window it moves around incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: So to clarify, I want it to look like this, even when the window resizes.

(http://students.cs.byu.edu/~drbones/Screenshot.png)

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, sean.daryl!

You can start by placing your `profile_image div` inside your `page div`, like so

```
<hr>

<div class="profile_image">
    <img src="images/sean_daryl_crop.jpg">
</div>

<!--EDUCATION-->
```

In this way, the image is contained within the rounded box.  (Assuming this is what you want.)

Comment: Ok, I see from your comment where you want it placed.  Why?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: My end goal is to be able to click on my name, and use jQuery to pop out that image right there.

Comment: You should consider opening the image in some sort of lightbox instead.  Having it appear at the side won't work properly if the screen size is small or if it is viewed on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

```
.profile_image {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
```

[image]

Use firebug mozilla

Comment: I tried that but if you resize the window horizontally it get's all messed up

Comment: for that you have to put fixed width for that div

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you wanted:

```
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1040px;
    overflow: hidden; // Or use clearfix
}

.profile_image {
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999999;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

.page {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    border: medium solid black;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999999;
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works specifying the width of the `.main` to place `.page` and `.profile_image` next to each other.

```
.main
    {
        padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:820px; /* CHANGE THIS just + your image size */
    }
.page
    {
        width:800px;
        float:left; /* this put the div at the start of the .main */
        border: solid black;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        background-color:#E8E8E8;
        border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
.profile_image
    {
        float:right; /* this put the div at the right of the .page */
        width:200px /* CHANGE to the image width */
    }
```